# How to open the SlidingPanelLayout, only through button?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an Android app with `GoogleMap` and I need to implement a `SlidingPanelLayout` in this Activity. 
I want to open the `SlidingPanelLayout` only when a certain button is clicked, because if I drag the finger 
on the `GoogleMap` the `SlindingPanelLayout` appears. So if I fix the open `SlidingPanelLayout` only when the button is clicked, the problem will be solved.

Are there any way to block the `SlidingPanelLayout` opening when I drag on the map, or something like this?

Answer (score 3):

If you really want the panel to open only through a button press, you should create a class that extends SlidingPaneLayout and override the onInterceptTouchEvent() method.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if(!isOpen()){
        //The map panel is being shown. We don't want the SlidingPaneLayout to handle the MotionEvent.
        return false;
    }
    else{
        //The other panel is being shown... Let the SlidingPaneLayout handle the MotionEvent as normal.
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Remember to use the custom SlidingPaneLayout class in your code or layout and not the regular one. Also, you should, obviously, place a button that will call the openPane() method of your custom class somewhere.

====

## THE APPROACH BELOW IS NOT THE ANSWER TO THE QUESTION, BUT AN ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION

Now, if you want to let the user to freely use the GoogleMap object and let the SlidingPaneLayout open if a drag event occur in a certain region of the screen/map, you can use this approach:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    //Get the user touch event position in dp units
    float xTouchPosDp = ev.getX()/getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    if(!isOpen()){
        if(xTouchPosDp < 30){
            //If the panel is closed (map pane being entirely shown) 
            //and the touch event occur on the first 30 horizontal dp's
            //Let the SlidingPaneLayout onTouchEvent() method handle the
            //motion event alone (the GoogleMap object won't receive the event
            //and depending on the movement, the panel will open)
            return true;
        }else{
            //Now, if the panel is closed, but the touch event occur
            //on the rest of the screen, let the GoogleMap object handle
            //the motion event.
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        //If the panel is opened, let the SlidingPaneLayout handle the 
        //motion event normally.
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Again, remember to use your custom SlidingPaneLayout class in your code/layout.

The problem with this solution is that if both panels are opened (they together fit the entire screen), you won't be able to move the map laterally.